# append hostname to /etc/hosts bash

Tags: bash

I am trying create a simple bash script that will add a record in the /etc/hosts file of my virtual machine. I've managed to do this successfully manually using:

```
echo sed -i '2i127.0.0.1 hostname.whatever.com hostname' /etc/hosts
```

But I would like to create a script that asks for the hostname and then creates it dynamically, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter hostname:"
read hostname
echo sed -i '2i127.0.0.1 $hostname hostname' /etc/hosts
```

This works fine but I would like to also be able to set the shortname "hostname" also. How would I take the first letters of the hostname variable before the .dot and also echo that in to the file correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Parameter expansion:

```
read -p "Please enter hostname: " hostname
echo "${hostname%%.*}"
```

Read into array:

```
IFS=. read -p "Please enter hostname: " -a hostname
echo "${hostname[0]}"
```

Both of these solutions uses native bash without forking a new process. The first one is also POSIX compliant, so it will work with /bin/sh.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name before the dot with `cut` like:

```
$ hostname=hostname.whatever.com
$ shortname=`cut -d. -f1 <<< $hostname`
$ echo $shortname
hostname
```